# How can I access fastboot and install recovery from here:

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, fastboot

I have a Toshiba Excite AT300SE, from 2012. I wish to install a custom recovery, through accessing `fastboot`, through accessing `adb`. However, whenever I run `adb`, it returns `error: device '(null)' not found`.

Here is the recovery screen: (screen that returns when I trigger Power+VolUp)

[image: Android system recovery for AT300SE]
(The blanked out option says `restart device now`)

I've tried out the following:

1. wipe data/factory reset
   It does not work
2. wipe cache, and then wipe data
   It also won't work
3. try using `adb [command]` while turning on (bootloop)
   `adb devices` returns null
4. apply update from ADB
   `adb devices` still returns null
5. apply update from external storage using the ROM uploaded [here](http://www.thriveforums.org/forum/dalepl/13661-rom-dalenet-imm76d-01-000072314-deodexed-stock-rooted-rom-us-ics-4-0-4-a.html)
   `Installation aborted` printed out after `Verifying update package...`

Any tips, Android StackExchange?

> Note: I don't have CWM, as shown evidently in the image
>
> Another note: It's stuck in a bootloop, so I can't turn on debugging mode.

Comment: Does your device boot normally? You can access the bootloader with adb, the phone must be on and debugging mode turned on.

Comment: @esQmo It's stuck in a bootloop.